# SiteMinder Post to FCC with C#

Tags: siteminder

I have been successful in posting to CA SiteMinder from the client, however, when I attempt to do a server side post I get no response from the server, but I do get a Status 200 (OK).  I should be getting SMSESSION back in the response, or response headers.  I get nothing back from the post.  So, my code is as follows (I posted my entire code behind file, just review the server side post method):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

namespace SiteMinder_SiteMinder_Side
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    com.ezmultifactor.demoappliance.Service1 service = new        com.ezmultifactor.demoappliance.Service1();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Request.Cookies["reauthen"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secureauthUri"] + "?returnSession="+Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["target"].Replace("-SM-","").Replace("$SM$","")));
        }
        else
        {
            LoadSession();

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientOrServerPost"] == "client")
            {
                ClientPost();
            }
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientOrServerPost"] == "server")
            {
                ServerPost();
            }
        }


    }

    protected string createPramString()
    {
        String Params = String.Empty;

        Params+=(String)Session["userName"]+"="+ Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["userNameValue"]);
        Params+="&"+(String)Session["password"]+"="+ Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["passwordValue"]);

        if ((String)Session["name1"] != "e" && (String)Session["value1"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name1"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value1"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name2"] != "e" && (String)Session["value2"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name2"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value2"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name3"] != "e" && (String)Session["value3"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name3"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value3"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name4"] != "e" && (String)Session["value4"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name4"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value4"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name5"] != "e" && (String)Session["value5"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name5"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value5"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name6"] != "e" && (String)Session["value6"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name6"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value6"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name7"] != "e" && (String)Session["value7"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name7"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value7"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name8"] != "e" && (String)Session["value8"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name8"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value8"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name9"] != "e" && (String)Session["value9"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name9"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value9"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name10"] != "e" && (String)Session["value10"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name10"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value10"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name11"] != "e" && (String)Session["value11"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name11"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value11"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name12"] != "e" && (String)Session["value12"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name12"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value12"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name13"] != "e" && (String)Session["value13"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name13"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value13"]);
        }

        return Params;
    }


    protected void ServerPost()
    {


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create((String)Session["PostURL"]);

        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = createPramString();
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";


        //request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        //request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        Response.Write(((HttpWebResponse)response).GetResponseHeader("SESSION"));


        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; ++i)
            Response.Write(response.Headers.Keys[i]+" : "+response.Headers[i]); 

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Response.Write(responseFromServer);



        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        Response.End();



    }



    protected void ClientPost()
    {



        //Create HTML Doc
            StringBuilder createhtm = new StringBuilder();
            createhtm.Append("<body onload=\"document.forms.SecurePass.submit()\">");

            createhtm.Append("<div>");
            createhtm.Append("<form action=\"" + (String)Session["PostURL"] + "\" method=\"post\" id=\"SecurePass\">");
            createhtm.Append("<input type=\"text\" style=\"display:none\" name=\"" + (String)Session["userName"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["userNameValue"] + "\">");
            createhtm.Append("<input type=\"password\" style=\"display:none\" name=\"" + (String)Session["password"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["passwordValue"] + "\">");

            if ((String)Session["name1"] != "e" && (String)Session["value1"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name1"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value1"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name2"] != "e" && (String)Session["value2"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name2"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value2"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name3"] != "e" && (String)Session["value3"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name3"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value3"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name4"] != "e" && (String)Session["value4"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name4"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value4"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name5"] != "e" && (String)Session["value5"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name5"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value5"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name6"] != "e" && (String)Session["value6"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name6"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value6"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name7"] != "e" && (String)Session["value7"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name7"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value7"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name8"] != "e" && (String)Session["value8"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name8"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value8"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name9"] != "e" && (String)Session["value9"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name9"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value9"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name10"] != "e" && (String)Session["value10"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name10"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value10"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name11"] != "e" && (String)Session["value11"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name11"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value11"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name12"] != "e" && (String)Session["value12"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name12"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value12"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name13"] != "e" && (String)Session["value13"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name13"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value13"] + "\">");
            } 


            createhtm.Append("</form>");
            createhtm.Append("</div>");
            createhtm.Append("</body>");

            Response.Write(createhtm);

    }

    protected void LoadSession()
    {
        //Response.Write(Request.Cookies["reauthen"].Value);
        //Response.End();
        String credential = service.DecryptData(Request.Cookies["reauthen"].Value);

        String[] splitcredential = credential.Split('_');

        Session["userName"] = "USER";
        Session["password"] = "PASSWORD";
        Session["userNameValue"] = splitcredential[1];
        Session["passwordValue"] = splitcredential[2];
        Session["PostURL"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["postURL"];





        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowSession"] == "true")
        {
            foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
            {
                Response.Write(key + "-" + Session[key] + "<br />");
            }
            Response.End();
        }


    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was easier than I expected, after pulling the headers from siteminder, I was able to pull the "set-cookie" header.  Inside that header is a string starting with "SMSESSION=" if you create a cookie called SMSESSION with the value from the header (i.e. the encrypted value after "SMSESSION=").  You will be able to redirect back to your protected resource logged in.

Be sure to pay close attention to the bottom of the encrypted string not to grab other values you don't want.

my code is as follows:

The parameter string may look a little confusing because I am calling other modules, but you should be able to get what you need out of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using MFA.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace SiteMinder_SiteMinder_Side
{
public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Config Values for Siteminder on this page are  
    // appsetting name "ClientOrServerPost" possible values "server"/"client"
    // appsetting name "postURL" possible values "This is the url of the .fcc file on the webserver"
    // appsetting name "ShowSession" possible values "true"/"false"
    // appsettings name "serviceurl" possible values "the URL of the tdez webservice"
    // appsettings name "CookieDomain" this is set in the admin "value should exist"


    com.ezmultifactor.demoappliance.Service1 service = new com.ezmultifactor.demoappliance.Service1();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



            LoadSession();

            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientOrServerPost"] == "client")
            {
                ClientPost();
            }
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientOrServerPost"] == "server")
            {
                ServerPost();
            }



    }
    //Specifically for the Server Post
    protected string createPramString()
    {
        String Params = String.Empty;

        Params+=(String)Session["userName"]+"="+ Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["userNameValue"]);
        Params+="&"+(String)Session["password"]+"="+ Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["passwordValue"]);

        if ((String)Session["name1"] != "e" && (String)Session["value1"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name1"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value1"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name2"] != "e" && (String)Session["value2"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name2"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value2"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name3"] != "e" && (String)Session["value3"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name3"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value3"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name4"] != "e" && (String)Session["value4"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name4"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value4"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name5"] != "e" && (String)Session["value5"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name5"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value5"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name6"] != "e" && (String)Session["value6"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name6"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value6"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name7"] != "e" && (String)Session["value7"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name7"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value7"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name8"] != "e" && (String)Session["value8"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name8"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value8"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name9"] != "e" && (String)Session["value9"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name9"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value9"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name10"] != "e" && (String)Session["value10"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name10"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value10"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name11"] != "e" && (String)Session["value11"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name11"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value11"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name12"] != "e" && (String)Session["value12"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name12"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value12"]);
        }
        if ((String)Session["name13"] != "e" && (String)Session["value13"] != "e")
        {
            Params += "&" + (String)Session["name13"] + "=" + Server.UrlEncode((String)Session["value13"]);
        }

        return Params;
    }


    protected void ServerPost()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create((String)Session["PostURL"]);

        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = createPramString();
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        String[] headers = new String[response.Headers.Count];

        //for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; ++i)
        //{
        //    Response.Write("*" + response.Headers.Keys[i] + "~" + response.Headers[i]);
        //    headers[i] = response.Headers.Keys[i] + "*" + response.Headers[i];
        //}

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();


        HttpCookie smsession = new HttpCookie("SMSESSION");
        smsession.Value = ripOutSession((String)((HttpWebResponse)response).GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"),"sessionData");
        smsession.Domain = ripOutSession((String)((HttpWebResponse)response).GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"), "domainData");
        smsession.Path = "/";
        smsession.Expires = Convert.ToDateTime(ripOutSession((String)((HttpWebResponse)response).GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"), "expireData"));
        Response.SetCookie(smsession);

        Response.Redirect((String)((HttpWebResponse)response).GetResponseHeader("Location"));

    }



    protected void ClientPost()
    {



        //Create HTML Doc
            StringBuilder createhtm = new StringBuilder();
            createhtm.Append("<body onload=\"document.forms.SecurePass.submit()\">");

            createhtm.Append("<div>");
            createhtm.Append("<form action=\"" + (String)Session["PostURL"] + "\" method=\"post\" id=\"SecurePass\">");
            createhtm.Append("<input type=\"text\" style=\"display:none\" name=\"" + (String)Session["userName"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["userNameValue"] + "\">");
            createhtm.Append("<input type=\"password\" style=\"display:none\" name=\"" + (String)Session["password"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["passwordValue"] + "\">");

            if ((String)Session["name1"] != "e" && (String)Session["value1"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name1"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value1"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name2"] != "e" && (String)Session["value2"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name2"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value2"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name3"] != "e" && (String)Session["value3"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name3"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value3"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name4"] != "e" && (String)Session["value4"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name4"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value4"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name5"] != "e" && (String)Session["value5"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name5"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value5"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name6"] != "e" && (String)Session["value6"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name6"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value6"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name7"] != "e" && (String)Session["value7"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name7"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value7"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name8"] != "e" && (String)Session["value8"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name8"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value8"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name9"] != "e" && (String)Session["value9"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name9"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value9"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name10"] != "e" && (String)Session["value10"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name10"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value10"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name11"] != "e" && (String)Session["value11"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name11"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value11"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name12"] != "e" && (String)Session["value12"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name12"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value12"] + "\">");
            }
            if ((String)Session["name13"] != "e" && (String)Session["value13"] != "e")
            {
                createhtm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + (String)Session["name13"] + "\" " + "value=\"" + (String)Session["value13"] + "\">");
            } 


            createhtm.Append("</form>");
            createhtm.Append("</div>");
            createhtm.Append("</body>");

            Response.Write(createhtm);

    }

    protected void LoadSession()
    {

        Session["userName"] = "USER";
        Session["password"] = "PASSWORD";
        Session["PostURL"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["postURL"];

        if (loginUserID() != "Empty")
        {
            LoadUserFromContext();
        }
        else
        {
            LoadUserDataFromCookie();
        }

        com.ezmultifactor.demoappliance.Service1 service = new com.ezmultifactor.demoappliance.Service1();
        service.Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceurl"];
        String userdelimpass = service.EncryptData("_" + Session["userNameValue"].ToString() + "_" + Session["passwordValue"].ToString() + "_Succsful");

        HttpCookie reauthen = new HttpCookie("reauthen");
        reauthen.Value = userdelimpass;
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieDomain"] != null)
        {
            reauthen.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CookieDomain"];
        }
        reauthen.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3.1);
        Response.SetCookie(reauthen);


        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShowSession"] == "true")
        {
            foreach (string key in Session.Keys)
            {
                Response.Write(key + "-" + Session[key] + "<br />");
            }
            Response.End();
        }


    }
    protected String ripOutSession(string validSessionHeader, string valuetoreturn)
    {
        String SMSESSION = validSessionHeader;

        String SMSESSIONMinusSpace = SMSESSION.Replace(" ", "");
        String[] SplitSession = SMSESSIONMinusSpace.Split(';');
        String SaveSession = String.Empty;
        String SaveDomain = String.Empty;
        String SaveExpire = String.Empty;
        String FinalResult = String.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < SplitSession.Length; i++)
        {

            if (SplitSession[i].Contains("SMSESSION"))
            {
                SaveSession = SplitSession[i];
            }
            if (SplitSession[i].Contains("domain"))
            {
                SaveDomain = SplitSession[i].Replace("domain=", "");
            }
            if (SplitSession[i].Contains("expires"))
            {
                SaveExpire = SplitSession[i].Replace("expires=", "");
            }

        }

        String[] splitSaveSession = SaveSession.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < splitSaveSession.Length; i++)
        {

            if (splitSaveSession[i].Contains("SMSESSION"))
            {
                SaveSession = splitSaveSession[i].Replace("SMSESSION=", "");
            }

        }


        if (valuetoreturn == "sessionData")
        {
            FinalResult=SaveSession;
        }
        if (valuetoreturn == "domainData")
        {
            FinalResult=SaveDomain;
        }
        if (valuetoreturn == "expireData")
        {
            FinalResult = SaveExpire;
        }

        return FinalResult;

    }
    public static String loginUserID()
    {
        try
        {

            string userid = "";

            ContextUser user = (ContextUser)HttpContext.Current.Session["currentuser"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.UserID.ToString()))
            {
                userid = user.UserID.ToString();
            }
            else { }

            return userid;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Empty";
        }

    }
    public static String loginUP()
    {
        string up = String.Empty;

        ContextUser user = (ContextUser)HttpContext.Current.Session["currentuser"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password.ToString()))
        {
            up = user.Password.ToString();
        }
        else { }

        return up;
    }
    protected void LoadUserFromContext()
    {

        String loginValue = loginUP();
        String RemoveDomain = loginUserID();
        bool containDomain;
        containDomain = (RemoveDomain.Contains("@"));
        string[] UserSplit = RemoveDomain.Split(new Char[] { '@' });

        if (containDomain == true)
        {
            RemoveDomain = UserSplit[0];
        }



        Session["userNameValue"] = RemoveDomain;
        Session["passwordValue"] = loginValue;



    }



    protected void LoadUserDataFromCookie()
    {

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
        String CookieDecryptedValueUserData = ticket.UserData.ToString();
        String CookieDecryptedValueUserName = ticket.Name.ToString();
        String RemoveDomain = CookieDecryptedValueUserName;

        bool containDomain;
        containDomain = (RemoveDomain.Contains("@"));
        string[] UserSplit = RemoveDomain.Split(new Char[] { '@' });

        if (containDomain == true)
        {
            RemoveDomain = UserSplit[0];
        }



        Session["userNameValue"] = RemoveDomain;
        Session["passwordValue"] = CookieDecryptedValueUserData;

    }


    }
}
```